# Create auto_incremented table name?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I am wondering how I could, using PHP and mysql, create a table with a unique name every time.

So example if i click submit, a table will be created that is named "1".
then if i do it again another table is added and it is named "2"

I searched around but could only find answers to how to auto_increment the columns inside the table so I hoped it would be the same code, I tried this:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY(TestColumn CHAR(30))");
```

It did not work.

So how do you create an auto_incremented table ???

Comment: I'm not sure if that's even possible within MySQL. I guess you could potentially use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS, and if it fails, increment the number and try again. It goes without saying that this approach is sub-optimal. I don't know why you need this, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it. Have you attempted to create temporary tables??

Comment: Put in in a loop, concatenate to some standard name the counter.

Comment: You could also parse the output of "show tables", fetch the highest "table name" and cast to integer, increment one and create new table.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Creating tables with meaningless names like `2` is something that infuriates people trying to work with your data.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple file which store a serial number. Then when your script creates a table, you increment the counter in the file with one. Next time, you read the number and use that for the table name. Naturally, you could do this in a table or a flat file.

Just for knowing which tables exist, and what they are for, you'd best create one master table storing not just the latest, but all tables created.

I am lost as to why you would want to do this.. I see no good reason for wanting this.

Comment: Or have a table which holds info about the dynamically created tables?

Comment: or create 10,000 tables and alter the structure as needed. I mean the possibilities are endless, but that system will be a hell to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I will never recommend to name a database table just with a digit. To keep track of number of click / page-load you can use file, session or another table.

Comment: You can get largest table by this query :


`*SELECT MAX(TABLE_NAME)+1 FROM information_schema.TABLES T WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'*`
 
And then add another table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table of tables and store the number or the number name in that table.  Then you can look up MAX number there.

Answer (score 0):

First at all, this function don't exist in PHP or in MySQL. Or maybe I don't know it.

There is 2 solutions to your problem :

**Solution number 1 :**

As AlanChavez said, you can use this request :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST ....
```

But, if you have to create 1000000000 table (it's an example), it will not be optimized.

**Solution number 2 :**

You can create a table with a single row, where is stored the last name used for your table.
I don't know if it's really optimized, but I think it can work.